# Error when printing a null in dojo dtl

Tags: javascript, dojo, django-templates

I have a basic widget written with Dojo that uses DTL to print a couple of variables. However, when one of those variables is null, it results in an error (str is null). Is it possible to solve or bypass this error? I would like it to print just an empty string...

I'm using dojo 1.9.0 in firefox 24.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Do you have some code that we can see?  It's difficult for us to help you if there is no code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, i ended up creating a patch so this would not happen.
This will return the string null.  if you want it to return empty sting uncomment the str="";

```
//Patch for DTL so it wont fail everytime there is a null value in JSON.
    require([ "dojox/dtl/_base"],function(){
        dojox.dtl._VarNode.prototype.render = function(context, buffer){
            var str = this.contents.resolve(context);
            if(str){
                if(!str.safe){
                    str = dojox.dtl._base.escape("" + str);
                }
            }else{
                writeLog("=====Value was Null::" + this.contents.key);
                //str="";
            }
            return buffer.concat(str);
        };
    });
```